# How to make recursive descent parsing recognise expressions

Tags: python, recursive-descent

I am making a graphing calculator and the issue I am having is finding a way to take in inputs like sin(90) and run my function for sin that I coded into another file.

I am using a recursive descent parser to go through each input and assign it to a token but the issue I am having is that when the user enters something like sin(90), the program checks each letter individually to try assign it to a token but since it doesn't recognise any token that is just an 's' or just an 'i', it outputs an error.

```
    def generate_tokens(self):  # Generate tokens from input
    while self.current_char is not None:
        if self.current_char in WHITESPACE:
            self.advance()  # If character is whitespace, skip it
        elif self.current_char == '.' or self.current_char in DIGITS:
            yield self.generate_number()  # If character is digit or decimal point, run next method
        elif self.current_char == '+':  # Specific token is generated if specific input 
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.PLUS)
        elif self.current_char == '-':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.MINUS)
        elif self.current_char == '*' or self.current_char == 'x':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.MULTIPLY)
        elif self.current_char == '/':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.DIVIDE)
        elif self.current_char == '(':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.LPAREN)
        elif self.current_char == ')':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.RPAREN)
        elif self.current_char == '^':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.INDICES)
        elif self.current_char == 's' and next(self.text) == 'i' and next(self.text) == 'n':
            self.advance()
            yield Token(TokenType.SIN)
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Illegal Character {self.current_char}')
```

Here is the code that generates a token for each input

I use a expression, term, factor rule and I put the sin function in the factor rule. Here is the code for the factor rule`   def factor(self):  # Highest level rule, checks for numbers
token = self.current_token  # Checks for numbers

```
    if token.type == TokenType.LPAREN:
        self.advance()
        result = self.expr()

        if self.current_token.type != TokenType.RPAREN:
            self.raise_error()

        self.advance()
        return result

    elif token.type == TokenType.NUMBER:
        self.advance()
        return NumberNode(token.value)

    elif token.type == TokenType.SIN:
        self.advance()
        return SinNode(self.factor())

    elif token.type == TokenType.PLUS:
        self.advance()
        return PlusNode(self.factor())

    elif token.type == TokenType.MINUS:  # Check if number is negative and then output it as negative
        self.advance()
        return MinusNode(self.factor())

    self.raise_error()`
```

And this goes to the interpreter which has this code.

`class Interpreter:
def visit(self, node):  # Pass in the root node here
method_name = f'visit_{type(node).**name**}'  # This tells us the type of node the node we are on is
method = getattr(self, method_name)
return method(node)

```
def visit_NumberNode(self, node):
    return Number(node.value)

def visit_AddNode(self, node):
    return Number(self.visit(node.node_a).value + self.visit(node.node_b).value)

def visit_SubtractNode(self, node):
    return Number(self.visit(node.node_a).value - self.visit(node.node_b).value)

def visit_MultiplyNode(self, node):
    return Number(self.visit(node.node_a).value * self.visit(node.node_b).value)

def visit_DivideNode(self, node):
    try:
        return Number(self.visit(node.node_a).value / self.visit(node.node_b).value)
    except:
        raise Exception('Runtime math error')

def visit_PlusNode(self, node):
    return self.visit(node.node)

def visit_MinusNode(self, node):
    return Number(-self.visit(node.node).value)

def visit_IndiceNode(self, node):
    return Number(self.visit(node.node_a).value ** self.visit(node.node_b).value)

def visit_SinNode(self, node):
    return Number(function.sin(self.visit(node.node.value)))
```

`
This is the code for the nodes

```
@dataclass
```

class SinNode:
node: any

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'(sin({self.node}))'
```

And this is the code for the values:

```
@dataclass
```

class Number:
value: float

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.value}'
```

I would appreciate any help because this project is really stressing me out. I can't figure out why it won't work and I have no idea how to make it work. I just need to read an expression from the user (something like 'x^2*tan(2x)') and apply it to np.linspace and graph that but I can't figure out a way to read the expression and keep order of operations correct. I also want to minimise use of libraries since there are libraries that do this but I need to do this without them

Comment: Since you are handling the string 1 character at a time can you not just pre-process it and represent each function as a single character. IE regex any expression "^sin(^)^" to "^s(^)^" for example (^ just means anything here since star doest work). It would then allow for the same descent method with minimal change. Just need to make sure there are not statements that already look like "^s(^)^", which should be illegal

Comment: How would I implement this, since the generate_tokens function only checks one character at a time. I tried making it so that it recognises the letter s and then runs the function sin(x) but the program fails since it doesn' take into account the other letters. I am new to python and haven't worked with regex before so sorry if this seems really basic

Comment: If you have access to the full string (you may not since you are using a generator) the most basic thing would be to do something like a string replace `s = s.replace("sin", "s")`?